# Crack a zip file password using lists instead of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to get this to work, but I am stuck in the loop section.  I cannot figure out how to set the proper loop and pick the right password!  Any help wold be appreciated.

```py
import zipfile

def openZip(file, password=''):
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(file)
    try:
        if password == '':
            zip.extractall()
        else:
            zip.extractall(pwd=bytes(password, 'utf-8'))
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        return False

passwords = ['qwerty', 'password', 'iloveyou', '123123', '111111', '12345', '12345678' , '1234567', '123456789', '123456']

file = input('What is the filename of the zip file? ')

for password in passwords:
    result = openZip(file, password)
    if result:
        print('the correct password is',password)
    else:
        print('incorrect:',password)
```

Comment: @BoarGules thanks for the suggestion.  It makes sense.  I made the change.  I still have no clue how I could connect with the "for" loop.  I've tried to use the "while" loop it was more complicated.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your loop does not work because it's not indented correctly. Also, consider what happens when you attempt to open a zip file with the wrong password.

Comment: @usr2564301 if the password is wrong, I'd get a message informing me that the password is wrong.  I'd add that as a print() but I just do not know how to use the loop to grab the strings and re-use if wrong.

Comment: @BoarGules when the user usr2564301 asked me what I'd expect if I opened the zip file with the wrong password, I answered based on a normal scenario (going to the actual file and try to extract its content by physically typing the wrong password).  I may have misunderstood their logic.

Comment: @BoarGules I see what you are saying.  If I remove the try ... except, I'd lose the cracking process.  The code runs now with no errors, but I have it set to print which prints all passwords instead of using them to crack the file!  I am not understanding what you are trying to tell me.  Perhaps you could show me?

Comment: @BoarGules It looks like I was able to extract the zip's files now (updated now).  The code used one of the strings in the list of "passwords".  The next step is to display what code was correct and which ones are wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for password in passwords:
    result = openZip(file, password)
    if result:
        print('the correct password is',password)
    else:
        print('incorrect:',password)
```

will print the passwords as needed.

Comment: This actually worked!

Comment: if result:
                       ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: that might be space in my code, replace them with tabs for indent

Comment: This worked!  Thank you.  I will be working next on displaying the wrong passwords (all of them) and then display the correct password with success vs failure.  Thank you for getting me closer.

Comment: any reason why it would only print after "else"?  Giving the scenario above, it would only print the incorrect, which in reality is the correct password!  Strange!

Comment: didn't understand the issue. explain more.

Comment: When I run the code, it only displays what the "else" does.  It does not display "if".  I only see one output which is the correct password, but it displayed under "incorrect"

Comment: use a debugger to find line which is wrong, it looks like the return value from `openZip` is messing things up.

Comment: nothing is wrong besides the "e" in line 11 not defined!

Comment: this is what it looks like: http://prntscr.com/qwn3fv